# Laravel post with comment error

Tags: php, laravel

So i created an app with login users and users can post, now the post is working just fine but when i put a comment function, i get an error "Invalid argument supplied for foreach()"

i have this in my Post model

```
<?php

    class Post extends Eloquent{

        protected $fillable = array('email', 'password','title','content');

        protected $table = 'posts';

        public function User()
        {
            return $this->belongsTo('User');
        }

        public function Comment()
        {
            return $this->hasMany('Comment', 'post_id');
        }
    }
```

And in my Comment model

```
<?php


    class Comments extends Eloquent {

        public function post()
        {
            return $this->belongsTo('Post');
        }
    }
```

and i have this in my Controller

```
public function viewPost($id)
    {   
        $post = Post::find($id);
        $user = Auth::user();
        $this->layout->content = View::make('interface.viewPost')->with('posts', $post )->with('users',$user);

    }
```

and in my views

```
<section class="comments">  
            @foreach($posts->comments as $comment)
            <blockquote>{{$comment->content}}</blockquote>
            @endforeach
        </section>
```

now when i try do run dd($posts->comment)

it returns a null because the comment table is empty. now what i want to know is why im getting this error? thanks for your help im just curious why this error is returning and i want to solve this one thanks

Comment: I am kind of new to Laravel but is `Post::find` a thing? Where did you find it?

Comment: http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/queries look at laravel docs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your Post Model `Comment` is the function name not the `comments` and Comment method making relation with wrong name model under hasMany method call.

```
public function Comment()
        {
            return $this->hasMany('Comments', 'post_id');
        }
```

Try to use

`@foreach($posts->Comment as $comment)`

If still inaccessible then try to eager loading.
like in your controller

`$post = Post::with("comment")->find($id);`

Comment: I tried your method but i returns this error. Class 'Comment' not found

Comment: Which method you using first one or second one?

Comment: the first one sir, have you checked my relationship method? is it correct?

Comment: i guessed it worked but it returns another error: Call to undefined method Comments::newQuery()

Comment: can you paste getting error? for better understand. because your scenario working fine to me with laravel 4.2.

Comment: And also can you update your question according to new changes?

Comment: use of irrelevant model name nothing else. thumbs up if you got your answer.

Comment: what model name ? haha

Comment: You just using wrong model name to define relation. :)